# Fail maven surefire-report job if any test failed

Tags: maven

I'm trying to configure a Maven job with tests that should do two things:

1. Generate HTML report with test results.
2. Fail if at least 1 test was failed during the run.

I thought it was a simple case and was stuck because one of the conditions always blocks the second. For example:

`mvn surefire-report:report site` - Maven result is always successful, not depending on the tests failures.

`mvn test surefire-report:report site` - the 'test' step generates an error, the following steps are ignored, and the report isn't generated. '--fail-at-end' flag didn't change anything in this case.

Is there any way to keep both my conditions in a single run: to generate a report and have some exit code on the tests failures?

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't find any way to do this except by using two different calls to maven:

```
mvn clean test <my params>
result=$?
mvn surefire-report:report-only site
exit $result
```

In this case, the first call gets and saves the exit code, which equals 1 if at least one failed test. The second call publishes reports and always returns the successful result, which I ignore.